# CakePHP 3.x search form with 11 different models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an application in CakePHP 3.5.13. The application is connected to a legacy database - that is to say it has not been written according to Cake's naming conventions.

I have baked the application which has generated some `Table` and `Entity` classes.

Part of the application allows the user to perform a search. I'm wanting to use the [Form Helper](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html) but am unsure how to name/configure things:

The template file where the search form lives has 11 text inputs. Each of these relates to data stored in the database. For brevity I'll consider the first 3 fields. These are associated with the `Table` classes:

- CAS Number - related to `CasTable`
- EC Number - related to `EcsTable`
- Substance Name - related to `SubstancesTable`

When opening the form tag I have done the following:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null, [
'url' => ['controller' => 'Front', 'action' => 'search'] ]); ?>
```

The reason I have passed `null` as the first parameter is because I don't know whether I'm supposed to use the instance of an `Entity` (as mentioned in the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#starting-a-form)), but wasn't sure which one, since there are 11 inputs all of which are associated with different `Table` classes. So I believe `null` to be correct here - Please can someone clarify this?

I'm also unsure how to name my inputs. For example the input searching for "CAS Number" needs to do a search on the database field `cas.value`. So would I name the input like this?

```
echo $this->Form->control('cas.value' ... );
```

I want to be able to validate each field according to rules that would be in the appropriate models. Because there are 11 different fields, and the form is not acting as either an "add" (SQL `INSERT`) or "edit" (SQL `UPDATE`) function, I cannot follow the Cake documentation to understand how I'm supposed to code this.

In summary what I'm trying to do is construct a HTML form - using Cake's Form Helper syntax - with 11 fields all of which are associated with appropriate models. I want to be able to validate the fields as per rules of those models. How can I do this? I have done research into it but cannot see any examples that do this - most focus on inserting/updating data. I also had a look at [Modeless Forms](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html) but don't think that's right because in this case I do have models for the search data.

At the moment I have simply written the form as vanilla HTML and can access the data posted to `FrontController::search()` through `$this->request->data()`. Whilst this works I believe this is a bad idea since I'd have to somehow run validation methods, and it may cause problems re-populating the form, or using the ORM later. I may be wrong here but am looking for a solution which uses Cake conventions, particularly focusing on correct use of the Form Helper in this type of situation.

Comment: did you try using cake naming convention for your controls as explained [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions)? 

It works even if your DB naming does not follows cake standard. 

You should see your controls validated according to each table rule. Remember you can create different validation sets to use in different situations (create, update, search...)

I also suggest using FriendsOfCake/search plugin

Comment: see also [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data)

Comment: I have named the form controls according to the docs, for example `<?php echo $this->Form->control('ecs.value', ['label' => 'EC Number']); ?>`. I don't really understand where to put the validation function or how to run it when the form is submitted to my controller. The docs - https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html - seem to be dealing with inserting/updating data and I am not doing that. I appreciate you sending the link to the plugin but it's way too complicated already even without adding on more things to read through.

Comment: the validation rules go in the table. Then - in the controller - when you post your data you can patch an entity even if you don't save it. See [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#validating-entities). Also the search plugin iss meant to simplify your job. Expecially when you have so many fields to search...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually see why you have to validate the search (I think that if one of the search inputs for some reason is not ok then the query will simply return zero records) but I guess you have your reasons so here is how to do it. Anyway this works even for saving entities so:

**Use naming Conventions**

First of all use g cake naming convention for your controls as explained [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions) and [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data)

It works even if your DB naming does not follows cake standard.

**Create validation rules**

Then in **each** of your table crete the validations set. You can create different validation for differents uses (save, update, search) (see [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#using-a-different-validation-set)). In your case you want to create a set for the search.

So in your tables (in every table!) you can create a method named `validationSearch`

```
public function validationSearch($validator)
{
    $validator
        ->add('title', 'notEmpty', [
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => __('You need to provide a title'),
        ]);
    return $validator;
}
```

**Patch the entity**

then in you `FrontController` you can do

```
$this->loadModel('Substances');
$substance = $this->Substances->newEntity(
    $this->request->getData(),
    [
        'validate' => 'search', // tells cake to use validateSearch
                                // for Substances Table
        'associated' => [
            'Cas' => [
                'validate' => 'search', // you want to use validateSearch
                                        // even for this table
            ],
            'Ecs'=> [
                'validate' => 'search', // and for this table, too
            ],
            // list of other related tables here
            // you can nest the array if you have
            // nested relationships
        ]
    ]
);
```

this will create an entity containing your data but above all it will check for validation issues and store the errors in the `$substance` entity.

```
$this->set('substance', $substance );
```

the above will pass your newly created entity to the form

**Create the form**

and finally in the view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create($substance , [ /*... */ ]); ?>
```

So the form knows about the entity, the validation rules to apply and the validation errors to show

**Create the controls**

Suppose you have a "main" table, meaning that all the other tables are somehow related to this. Let's say it is Substances. So follow the conventions.

```
<?= $this->Form->control('name', ['label' => 'Substance name') ?> 
//                        ^ No need to prepend the table here
<?= $this->Form->control('cas.number', ['label' => 'Cas number') ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('ecs.number', ['label' => 'Ecs number') ?>
```

**Use a plugin**

And consider using using FriendsOfCake/search plugin. With so many fields to check it will simplify your life

Comment: Hmm the trouble with this is that although I have a `FrontController.php`, there is no `'front'` table or model - so I don't think `$this->Front` makes sense. This is why I was confused about what to use in `$this->Form>create`. The 11 form fields are essentially tied to 11 different models, and I need to have validation functions in them all. If the user completes just 4 of the 11 fields, it would run validation in those 4 models etc. The reason for validating is that if someone searches "CAS Number" (for example) there is a specific format that a valid CAS number can have.

Comment: I Guess that your tables are related. Did you set the relationships? If so just find the one table that you consider the 'main' one and create an entity of it.

Comment: Yes, the main table is the `substances` one, for which there is a corresponding Table and Entity class. So I guess `$this->Substances` will do.

Comment: If you do in frontcontroller then you have to call loadtable('Substances')

Comment: I've got that working. But how can I validate *different* input fields against their own validation functions? At the moment, the entire request (`$this->request->getData()`) is being validated by `validateSearch`. This won't work because there are separate validation requirements for all 11 fields.

Comment: create a validateSearch method for every table

Comment: I've implemented what's said but unfortuantely it's not working. All I can get back in terms of errors is: `'[errors]' => [
  'name' => [
   '_empty' => 'This field cannot be left empty'
  ]
 ],` which validates the "substance name" (`name`) field. It even gives this error when there's text in the input! Someone has mentioned on the further question I asked about using a Modeless form. I'm going to consider this, and if it doesn't work, just do it in the controller!

Comment: Well, this depends on your validation code, i guess

Comment: The trouble is, that validation message isn't anywhere in my code. I searched the entire `src/` directory and it's not there. I even commented out the `validationDefault` methods. This is way more complex than it needs to be so I've decided to abandon trying for now. Thanks for your input though.