# CakePHP 3.x not giving validation error when 'return false' supplied

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This question somewhat follows on from a previous question I asked about implementing validation when performing a search in a Cake 3.x application: [CakePHP 3.x search form with 11 different models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130427/cakephp-3-x-search-form-with-11-different-models)

I've been reading the documentation on [Using Custom Validation Rules](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#using-custom-validation-rules).

I have added the following to my `Model/Table/EcsTable.php`:

```
public function validationSearch($validator)
{
    $extra = 'Some additional value needed inside the closure';
    $validator->add('value', 'custom', [
    'rule' => function ($value, $context) use ($extra) {
        return false;
    },
    'message' => 'The title is not valid'
    ]);
    return $validator;
}
```

This is a copy of what is given in the docs except I have added `return false` because I'm trying to test the validation method producing an error.

In my Controller I have the following:

```
$ecs_entity = TableRegistry::get('Ecs')->newEntity(
$this->request->getData(),
[
    'validate' => 'search', // tells cake to use validateSearch
]
);
```

I cannot get this to generate a validation error. If I submit my form (so that the request data is submitted) and then do `debug($ecs_entity);` the `errors` property is an empty array:

```
object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {
    'ecs' => [
        'value' => '124'
    ],
    // ...
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Ecs'
}
```

Why is this? I am planning on writing logic inside my closure inside `validationSearch` which validates the data passed. However, I can't even get it to produce an error so haven't gone this far with it. Am I implementing this in the wrong way?

As per the original question I'm trying to do things in the proper "Cake way" of writing validation. I'm getting to the point where I'm seriously considering abandoning it and just sticking everything in the Controller, because it's so tedious to pass the data around - and involves more lines of code when I could just validate it right there in the controller.

Comment: I think the problem is in the form. In fact your entity should not contain an 'ecs' parameter. Try to debug your $this->request->getData()

Comment: I guess you have a control like 'ecs.value'. But in the other question you said your 'main' table was Substances. So create a Substance entity and all the related entities will be validated as well. I'm going to edit the other answer

Comment: Yes I did have `ecs.value` due to my confusion from the original linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are passing to the `newEntity` call is not in valid format.

It looks like you are passing something like

```
    [
        'ecs' => [
            'value' => 123 
        ] 
    ]
```

When it should be:

```
[ 'value' => 123  ]
```

The **debug** output for a **valid** `Ecs` entity should look like this:

```
object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

    'value' => '123',
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'value' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Esc'

}
```

As you can see `value` is a *direct* property of the object.

Without seeing your `Form` I can guess you have created it like:

`$this->Form->control( 'ecs.value')`

instead of

`$this->Form->control( 'value' );`

Comment: Yes I had written `ecs.value` in the form. The linked question in my original post might explain why. Thank you for this clarification.

Comment: I see. In this case you may be better off using the `Validator` API directly and a Modelless form to do the validations and get the proper error messages into the Front End. Since you are not saving the form into the database, this is a "cake way" of doing things, because you validate the input in a forms against some _known rules_. But you are not creating new entities into the db, so no need to link into Table Models. You can get fancy and use Validation providers so you can reuse the same code for the DB Tables if you need to, but it may be overkill at this point.